# Unexpected output with integer

Tags: c, cs50

I write the program, but output is not correct. I looked at code for 3 days, but still can't find the mistake.

```
// Calculate your half of a restaurant bill
// Data types, operations, type casting, return value

#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

float half(float bill, float tax, int tip);

int main(void)
{
    float bill_amount = get_float("Bill before tax and tip: ");
    float tax_percent = get_float("Sale Tax Percent: ");
    int tip_percent = get_int("Tip percent: ");

    
    printf("You will owe $%.2f each!\n", half(bill_amount, tax_percent, tip_percent));
}

// TODO: Complete the function
float half(float bill, float tax, int tip)
{
  // Calculate bill with tax
    float tax_amount = bill * (tax/100);
    // Calculate tip amount
    // My second mistake is that i didn't calculate tip separately from the tax
    // My third mistake. I didn't typecast tip
    float tip_amount = bill * (tip/100);
    // Calculate final bill
    // My first mistake. I calculated tax and tip but didn't sum with the bill
    float total_bill = bill + tax_amount + tip_amount;
    // Split final bill in a half
    float half = total_bill / 2;
    return half;
}
```

Input: Bill of $50, with 10% tax and 20% tip, creates output of $33.00. Expected Output: 33.00.Actual Output: You will owe $32.50 each!

Comment: `tip/100` is an integer division. If `tip` is less than `100` then the result will be zero.

Comment: `tip/100` is `0` because of integer division. Use `tip/100.0`

Comment: Unrelated: prefer `double` when dealing with floating-point values.

Answer (score 3):

`100` is an [integer constant](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/integer_constant), of type `int`. `tip` is also of type `int`, meaning no *type conversion* takes place, and `tip / 100` performs *integer division*, effectively truncating any would-be digits to the right of the decimal place. The result of this expression remains an `int`.

On the other hand, `100.0f` is a [floating constant](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/floating_constant), of type `float`. If you used the expression `tip / 100.0f`, it would be subject to an [implicit type conversion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Usual_arithmetic_conversions), where `tip` is converted from an `int` to a `float`, and floating-point division would occur. The result of the expression would be a `float`.

When in doubt, be explicit with your [constants](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/expressions#Constants_and_literals).

```
#include <stdio.h>

float half(float bill, float tax, int tip)
{
    float tax_amount = bill * (tax / 100.0f);
    float tip_amount = bill * (tip / 100.0f);

    return (bill + tax_amount + tip_amount) / 2.0f;
}

int main(void)
{
    printf("%.2f\n", half(50.0f, 10.0f, 20));
}
```

```
32.50
```

---

Alternatively, `100.0` is a [floating constant](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/floating_constant), of type `double`. In the following

```
float tip_amount = bill * (tip / 100.0);
```

`tip` would be converted from an `int` to a `double`, and division would take place, resulting in a `double`. `bill` would then be converted from a `float` to a `double`, and multiplication would take place, resulting in a `double`.

Finally, the `double` would be converted back to a `float` to satisfy the variable type.

Answer (score 0):

- `tip/100` is an `int/int` with an `int` quotient.  OP certainly wants a floating point division.
- Best to perform financial calculations using whole number math.  That is, the bill, tax and tip should each be correct to the 0.01.  As typical floating-point types do not encode such values exactly, round when necessary.
- Debatable if tip should be based on `amount` or `amount+tax`.  Both approaches shown below.

---

```
#include <math.h>

float half(float bill, float tax, int tip) {
  // Convert money to an integer number of lowest currency denomination.
  long long amount = llround(bill * 100.0);
  // Is the tip based on the bill or the bill + tax?
  #if TIP_ON_TAX_TOO
    amount += llround(amount * (tax / 100.0));
    amount += llround(amount * (tip / 100.0));
  #else
    amount += llround(amount * (tax / 100.0)) + llround(amount * (tip / 100.0));
  #endif
  // Round away from 0 to the nearest even cent.
  if (amount % 2) {
    amount += amount % 2;
  }
  amount /= 2;
  return amount / 100.0f;
}
```